# Passenger + Capistrano + Apache = Rails app not running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, apache, capistrano, passenger

I'm trying to deploy my rails app with capistrano.

This is exactly the problem i'm experiencing, only the fix isn't working for me. I've pasted my info below.

/var/www/vhosts/example.us/conf/vhost.conf

```
ServerName example.us
ServerAlias example.us
DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/example.us/current/public
PassengerAppRoot /var/www/vhosts/example.us/current

<Directory "/var/www/vhosts/example.us/current/public">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>

RailsEnv development
RailsBaseURI /httpdocs
```

I've also tried `RailsBaseURI /`

ls -l from `/var/www/vhosts/example.us` on some the important directories (not showing the permissions)

```
current -> /var/www/vhosts/example.us/releases/20120809050127
httpdocs -> current/public/
```

Can someone please point me in the direction of what's causing passenger to not see my rails app?

**EDIT**

It seems that it has something to do with capistrano's "current" symlink. When i move my rails app to the server via ftp and then change my vhost.conf to point to my projects public folder rather than the current/public folder, it seems to work.

How can I resolve the issue with capistrano's symlink if that's the underlying issue? I would have thought that the `PassengerAppRoot` would have solved this.

**EDIT**

This line appears in the error log

```
[Sun Aug 12 18:02:07 2012] [error] [client 11.1.1.111] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/
```

Comment: Are you sure the passenger module is enabled and included? If yes, have you restarted the server?

Comment: Yes i've restarted the server. How can I check if the passenger module is enabled and included? I have another project running on the server that is using passenger and if i type `passenger-status`, it returns general information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I hadn't run

```
/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/httpdmng --reconfigure-domain xxx.xx.xx.xx
```

so apache was actually not looking at my vhosts.conf file.